# how works variable fonts

Tags: css, webfonts

I have bought this [variable font](https://www.youworkforthem.com/font/T12173/aventa-variable-typeface/typetester/) for web use but the "variable system" don' t work .
here is css :

```css
/*      this part was given by the site where I bought the font so the problem certainly does not come from there       */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AventaVariable' ;
    src: url('aventa.eot') ;
    src: url('aventa.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype') ,
             url('aventa.woff2') format('woff2') ,
         url('aventa.woff') format('woff') ,
         url('aventa.ttf') format('truetype') ,
         url('aventa.svg#youworkforthem') format('svg') ;
    font-weight: normal ;
    font-style: normal ;
}
/*      my css      */
.someelements {
    font-family: 'AventaVariable' ;
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 100 ;
    font-weight: 100 ;

}
```

I tried to open a random variable font file (KairosSans_Variable.ttf) :
[image]

and here is my variable font file (aventa-variable.ttf) 
[image]

so you see it isn't the same type

why it don't work ?

Comment: Check [caniuse: variable fonts](https://caniuse.com/#feat=variable-fonts), maybe some requirement not met? Or not supported by your browser? Please supply some [reprex]...

Comment: You should check with your browser developer-tools if the font can be found and if the browser supports 'variable font' settings. Removed the comment yet???

Comment: in fact the font is properly displayed it's just that the font-weight ( and font variation setting ) has no effect . I am on Chrome btw

Comment: When you open the 'example.html' that came with the font, you will see that either Chrome/Edge(use the same browser code) or Firefox show that this is an illegal value: `-moz-font-feature-settings: 'aalt=0,ccmp=0,dlig=0,dnom=0,frac=0,liga=0,locl=0,numr=0,ordn=0,salt=0,ss01=0,sups=0'` when you inspect one of the texts. Not all settings of variable fonts are widely supported. Will need to fiddle with those....

Comment: To be able to help you better, post some [reprex] you are using (html+css)

Comment: https://codepen.io/adanisovaslav/pen/qBOvVPr  the font feature settings you gave me returns an illegal value but the one I set don't . the problem is that I have any illegal value , the font is correctly displayed but the weight , the font variation & feature change anything to the text .

Answer (score 0):

the font weight varies between 1000 and 1900 , ( I had tried between 100 and 800 ) that's why the font weight didn't affect the text .